# Limit Zoom Levels in ArcGIS Online WebMap

Tags: arcgis-online, scale, zoom, arcgis-web-appbuilder, visibility

I am adding a feature class to a WebMap that I am then incorporating into a WebApp using WebApp Builder for ArcGIS. I have set the visibility scale on my feature class as I would like it. When accessing the WebApp, and zooming to a feature, it zooms to the closest possible level.

Is there anyway to limit how far the zoom-in goes? Does this have to be done on the WebMap side, some configuration I can set? Or can I edit some .json config files from the WebApp files to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using any base layers? If so, which one?

Comment: The standard ESRI basemaps. There is a basemap gallery on the WebApp so the user can choose whicever they prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Web AppBuilder you can limit the scale that an be zoomed to:

[image]

One dirty workaround I saw for doing this at the Web Map level would be to add a dummy cached basemap (e.g. empty tile package with your desirable levels of detail/scales).

Comment: Related: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/177441

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the configuration of "Find, Edit, and Filter" [developed](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/find-edit-filter/get-started/additional-configuration/#configuration-values) by Esri to go beyond the configuration of the set parameters of your Web app.

> After accessing the application code from GitHub and modifying the configuration file. The configuration file, FindEditFilter.json, can be opened in a text editor such as Notepad, but an IDE such as Visual Studio is recommended for easier reading.
>
> Making these additional configuration changes does not require knowledge of JavaScript or JSON, but attention to details such as the locations of parentheses and commas is critical. It is strongly recommended that you 'lint' the configuration file code frequently using a website such as http://jsonlint.com/ to be certain you have not introduced syntax errors into the configuration file.
>
> After modifying the configuration file, host your modified configuration as a new application template in ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS, or host the application on a web server.

The following additional configurations are available through the JSON configuration file:

Add locator search
Modify configuration panel parameters
Modify color schemes
Modify icons
Set default configuration values
Show splash screen
Show search as a sidebar

In the set default configuration values [here](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/find-edit-filter/get-started/additional-configuration/#configuration-values) you will be able to specify the zoom level you prefer when selecting a feature.

Just for additional context, [here](zoom level when selecting feature arcgis web app) is a forum discussion on basemap layers and default zoom as well as an Esri blog [entry](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/03/21/whats-new-with-the-finder-app-for-arcgis-online-formerly-known-as-parcel-viewer/) that gives an overview of all the configure options allotted for web apps.

Comment: Can I set zoom levels for the basemap?

Comment: Yes, when you use the configuration file as mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: This is from ArcGIS for Local Government yes? Don't think I have that

Comment: Free to access - http://solutions.arcgis.com/#Local Government

Comment: Guess I was looking for something inside the box, a quick fix that doesn't require additional software